# How to create locks in VC++?

Tags: windows, multithreading, winapi, visual-c++, locks

Lets say I am implementing a critical section and protecting some array in VC++, how do I do it using locks in VC++?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need the API functions for [critical sections](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682530%28v=VS.85%29.aspx):

- [`InitializeCriticalSection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683472%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) Call once, from any thread, but typically the main thread, to initialize the lock. Initialize before you do anything else with it.
- [`EnterCriticalSection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682608%28VS.85%29.aspx) Call from any thread to acquire the lock. If another thread has the lock, it will block until it can acquire the lock. Critical sections are re-entrant meaning a thread successfully acquires the lock even if it already holds it.
- [`LeaveCriticalSection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684169%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) Release the lock. Each call to `EnterCriticalSection` must be paired with a matching call to `LeaveCriticalSection`. Don't let exceptions stop these acquire/release calls being paired up.
- [`DeleteCriticalSection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682552%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) Call once, from any thread, but typically the main thread, to finalize the lock. Do this when no threads hold the lock. After you call this the lock is invalid and you can't attempt to acquire it again.

MSDN helpfully provide a [trivial example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686908%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

If you are using MFC then you would probably use [`CCriticalSection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h5zew56b%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) which wraps up the Win32 critical section APIs in a class.

As for how you do it with your array. Well, your threads will only execute blocks of code protected by the lock one at a time. You need the lock to stop race conditions where two threads try to read/write to the same memory location simultaneously, or indeed other more subtle conditions that can break your algorithm.

If you were to describe the array, its contents, and how you operate on it, then it might be possible to give you some specific advice. Exactly how you operate on this array will have a large bearing on the ideal synchronisation strategy, and in certain cases you may be able to use lock-free methods.

Answer (score 2):

Create a mutex via [CreateMutex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682411%28VS.85%29.aspx), take ownership of it via [WaitForSingleObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms687032%28VS.85%29.aspx), release ownership of the mutex via [ReleaseMutex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms685066%28VS.85%29.aspx), and deleted it when you are done with [CloseHandle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724211%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Alternatives you can look up include [CriticalSections](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682608%28VS.85%29.aspx), [Semaphores](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682438%28VS.85%29.aspx), and [Events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682396%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Just to add to your answer, mutexes can be used across processes, in contrast to critical sections which only work for threads within a single process. On the flip side, critical sections perform better and are re-entrant.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using VS 2010, a [`criticial_section`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492843.aspx) object is included in the header file ppl.h.

Note there is also a `concurrent_vector` class template which is synchronized (i.e. locks aren't needed).

Comment: This `critical_section` class is part the concurrency runtime rather than straight Win32 and is non re-entrant. These are important points.