# Access Violation In Multithreaded C Application

Tags: c, multithreading, winapi, mutex, access-violation

I'm trying to write a simple C application that is multithreaded. I want the main thread to be suspended until some flag is set by the worker thread. So for my thread function param I pass a struct that includes the flag. When I assign the flag in the worker thread, I get an access violation. I am using a Mutex to theoretically prevent simultaneous access to this struct instance that is being shared between the main app and the worker thread. Can someone point me in the right direction? The full project code is below. I have denoted the error line in comments in the THREADFUNCS.C file.

GLOBALS.H

```
#ifndef _globals_h
#define _globals_h

#include <windows.h>


static HANDLE ghMutex;


#endif
```

THREADCOM.H

```
#ifndef _threadcom_h
#define _threadcom_h

typedef struct { 
   char bContinueMain;
} RComData;

#endif
```

THREADFUNCS.H

```
#ifndef _threadfuncs_h
#define _threadfuncs_h 

#include <windows.h>

extern DWORD WINAPI ThreadA(LPVOID params);

#endif
```

THREADFUNCS.C

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "threadcom.h"
#include "threadfuncs.h"
#include "globals.h"

DWORD WINAPI ThreadA(LPVOID params)
{
   RComData* pr = (RComData*)params;
   int i;

   printf("You are in thread A.\n");
   WaitForSingleObject(ghMutex, INFINITE);
   pr->bContinueMain = TRUE; /* ACCESS VIOLATION HERE */
   ReleaseMutex(ghMutex);
   for (i=0; i<10; ++i)
   {
      printf("Printing THREAD A line %i.\n", i);
   }
}
```

MAIN.C

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "threadfuncs.h"
#include "threadcom.h"
#include "globals.h"

void WaitForGoAhead(RComData* pr)
{
   char bGo = FALSE;
   while (!bGo)
   {
      WaitForSingleObject(ghMutex, INFINITE);
      if (pr->bContinueMain)
         bGo = TRUE;
      ReleaseMutex(ghMutex);
   }
}

int main(void)
{
   int i;
   HANDLE hThreadId = -1;
   RComData r = { FALSE };

   hThreadId = CreateThread(0, 0, ThreadA, 0, &r, &hThreadId);
   WaitForSingleObject(hThreadId, 1);
   if (hThreadId > 0)
   {
      printf("Thread has been launched.\n");
      ghMutex = CreateMutex(0, FALSE, 0);
      WaitForGoAhead(&r);
      for (i=0; i<10; ++i)
      {
         printf("Printing main proc line %i.\n", i);
      }
      WaitForSingleObject(hThreadId, INFINITE);
      printf("Thread is complete.\n");
      CloseHandle(ghMutex);
      CloseHandle(hThreadId);
   }
   else
   {
      printf("Thread failed to created.\n");
   }

   printf("Press any key to exit...");
   getchar();
   return 0;
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Who uses mutexes for this sort of lock anyway? Surely you'd want a critical section?

Comment: Well then that's something for me to look into. The problem is that I've been living in .NET-land for too long and now I'm trying to go backwards and learn the hard way to do everything :-)

Comment: Within a single process, the Critical Section is much better than a Mutex. Easier to use, faster, etc. They are both mutexes in the general sense of the term, a mutual exclusion, one owner at a time object. I wrote a detailed answer about critical sections quite recently: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5054114/how-to-create-locks-in-vc

Answer (score 6):

You need to create the mutex *before* you create the thread.

Right now your thread will WaitForSingleObject on an invalid handle

Answer (score 3):

The parameter `&r` should be the 4th parameter in the CreateThread call.  It is currently 0 (null), which would cause an access violation when you dereference the pointer in the thread function.

Comment: +1: Answers the OP's question correctly, as opposed to my answer which deals with another bug.

Comment: @Eric - Nonetheless, your answer covers the arguably more subtle problem :).  +1

Comment: Thanks. Don't know how I missed that.

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple static variables called ghMutex (one in main.c, one in threadfuncs.c). You should combine these into a single mutex, then initialise it before you create the new thread.

in globals.h:

```
extern HANDLE ghMutex;
```

in main.c:

```
HANDLE ghMutex = 0;
```

In main.c move the mutex initialisation before the thread is created.

Comment: Aw, shoot. I'm falling back into C# habits there. Thanks.